# code first get values from foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, code-first

I've started a sample project with code first and get NULL value from entity which has a foreign key constraint.

my model:

```
public class CustomerItem
{
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int Name{get;set;}
     public virtual IEnumerable<OrderItem> Order { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerItem")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerItem CustomerItem { get; set; }
}
```

dataaccess linq query to get values:

```
public IEnumerable<CustomerItem> GetOrdersFromCustomerItem(int id)
{
    return (from c in this.dax.Customer
           where c.Id.CompareTo(id) == 0
           select c).AsEnumerable().ToList();
}
```

this query return NULL orders so I think there's some mistake in this query.
How can I wire up this entity with foreign key table?

Thanks

**Updated** my query to get all customers (and their orders) to this:

```
public IEnumerable<CustomerItem> GetAllCustomers()
{
    return (from c in this.dax.Customer
            select new 
            {
                //Properties
                OrderItem = c.OrderItem
            }).AsEnumerable.ToList().select(s => new CustomerItem
            {
               //Properties
               OrderItem = s.OrderItem, //here I got the exception I wrote in comment
            }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<OrderItem> Order { get; set; }
```

To:

```
public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> Order { get; set; }
```

Since `IEnumerable<>` exposes read-only methods, `Entity Framework` is basically ignoring it. the property must be of writeable collection type in order to map it to the database.

It is quite common though, to expose an `IEnumerable` property, and have it's `getter` returning a `backing-field` that is really an `IList/ICollection`.

Comment: oh, found the solution at the same time. I'll delete my answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the following :

```
public IEnumerable<CustomerItem> GetOrdersFromCustomerItem(int id)
{
  // You must select CustomerItem not a customer in the previous linq query.
  return (from c in this.dax.Customer
       where c.Id.CompareTo(id) == 0
       select new CustomerItem{

        }).AsEnumerable().ToList();
}
```

Comment: hi minhcat, thanks for your answer but it's still not working after some changes. I've updated my question with my new query and I got this exception "Specified type member not supported in LINQ to Entities". I found some posts about this exception like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018135/specified-type-member-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities, but I think the types which I'm using should be known by linq-to-entities.