# Convert string to enum in Linq to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0, type-conversion

How to convert string to enum in Linq using C#?

Does the type casting below also work in linq?:

```
(Audience)Enum.Parse(typeof(Audience), value, true);
```

If yes, please tell me how I can use this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426577/how-to-use-flags-enums-in-linq-to-entities-queries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the enum

```
enum Foo{A, B, C}
```

the code below performs conversion from `enum` to `string` and vice-versa:

```
var values = 
from name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Foo))
select (Foo)Enum.Parse(typeof(Foo), name, true);
```

So, yes the casting works. However, keep in mind that the query above will throw an `ArgumentException` if `Enum.Parse` method receives a value that cannot be parsed.

This updated version only returns values that parse sucessfully

```
enum Foo{A, B, C}

var values =  
   from name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Foo))
   where Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Foo), name)
   select (Foo)Enum.Parse(typeof(Foo), name, true);
```

Comment: Enum.IsDefined can be used to avoid ArgumentException

Comment: @Tilak, thank you. The updated version can be found at http://pastebin.com/pyQ9xPv5