# How to return values from Entity Framework with parameters based on a bitwise Enum

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bitwise-operators

Bit (sorry) confused about how to use bitwise operators with Entity Framework.

A recent requirement has necessetated that we alter an enum from a series of sequential integers into a bitwise enum. So:

```
[Flags]
public enum AdminLevel
{
    None = 0,
    Basic = 1,
    Partial = 2,
    Full = 4
}
```

We originally stored this as an int column in the database. It's still an int, of course, but I'm having trouble seeing how I can perform selections based on more than one possible enum value. For example this code:

```
public string GetAdminEmails(AdminLevel adminlevel)
{
    using (IRepository r = Rep.Renew())
    {
        string[] to = r.GetUsers().Where(u => u.AdminLevel >= (int)adminlevel).Select(u => u.Email).ToArray();
        return string.Join(",", to);
    }
}
```

Would return all the admin levels including and above the one supplied. If I want more than one admin level, I now have to call it like this:

```
GetAdminEmails(AdminLevel.Partial | AdminLevel.Full);
```

But obviously I can't convert that to an int and use greater than any more. Is there a neater way of handling this change than a series of flow control statements?

Comment: It sounds like you want `GetAdminEmails(AdminLevel.Partial | AdminLevel.Full)` to mean "get admin emails above `AdminLevel.Partial` OR `AdminLevel.Full`". Is that right? If that's what you want, you're going to need to do something clever to decompose the flagged enum into a sequence of OR predicates... or you could figure out what the lowest set flag is and use that in your query.

Comment: @SteveRuble That's right, thanks. What's confused me is some isolated suggestions that EF has a certain level of inbuilt ability to recognize and work with bitwise values. I wondered if there was a neater way to handle this.

Comment: People already discussed related to this topic. It might helpful .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426577/how-to-use-flags-enums-in-linq-to-entities-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HasFlag` method:

```
AdminLevel myFlags = AdminLevel.Partial | AdminLevel.Full;
string s = GetAdminEmails(myFlags);

public string GetAdminEmails(AdminLevel myFlags)
{
  using (IRepository r = Rep.Renew())
  {
      string[] to = r.GetUsers().Where(u => u.AdminLevel.HasFlag(myFlags))
                                .Select(u => u.Email).ToArray();
      return string.Join(",", to);
  }
}
```

You can define an `int` column in your database as an enumeration in your model:

```
public enum MyEnum : int { First = 0, Second = 1}

public partial class MyModel
{
   public MyEnum Type {get; set;}
}
```

Throughout your application you can just use `MyEnum` and EF will work with `int` on the background.

Comment: OK, it looks like I'm asking the wrong question. I came across HasFlag while searching for a solution, but I don't seem to have access to it. We're using EF database first and my field is an int, not an enum?

Comment: @MattThrower Just define your Model as `AdminLevel` instead of `int`, EF does the conversion automatically

Comment: You can as well use '.HasColumnType("INT")' in mapping of your Context and in your entity model should have AdminLevel type as already recommended

Comment: @MattThrower yes, I'm using Database first too mainly and for a lot of `int` `byte` `short` I have defined enumerations. It's just a lot easier to work with. Edited my answer with an example.